# Compile multiple LESS files using the Windows Command Prompt

Tags: windows, node.js, command-line, less

I am trying to automate a process using the windows command line. Part of this automation is compiling a couple of files from .less to .css. I have successfully installed node.js and the LESS compiler using the npm.

I have a Command Prompt Script (.cmd) which contains the folowing commands:

```
echo Compiling CSS...   
pause
lessc -x C:\path_to_file\file1.less > ..\output\file1.css
pause
lessc -x C:\path_to_file\file2.less > ..\output\file2.css
pause
```

The first lessc command works without any compile errors, and saves file1.css to the output folder as expected.

The command line then quits without even hitting the second pause command, let along asking for user input.

I don't understand why the command prompt is quitting. Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: `lessc` in Windows is a command line script itself (`lessc.cmd`) so the first command transfers control to `lessc.cmd` and never returns back to your own script. `call lessc` should help. (Also `>` is not necessary and may cause additional problems depending on input/output paths and options used).

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I was beginning to wonder if this was the case, but I didn't know a work around. I'll give `call` a try.

Comment: `call` seems to work perfectly. Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As seven-phases-max stated, less is a command line script in windows and does not return back to the original script.

The work-around is to use `call`. The script ended up being:

```
echo Compiling CSS...   
pause
call lessc -x C:\path_to_file\file1.less ..\output\file1.css
pause
call lessc -x C:\path_to_file\file2.less ..\output\file2.css
pause
```

All credit goes to seven-phases-max, i just wanted to clarify the correct method as it may help others in the future.